# How to prevent my angular sidenav from hiding the toolbar?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to design an angular component made of a toolbar and below a sidenav. Here is the corresponding HTML code for my component:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    Toolbar Title
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav class="mat-elevation-z8" mode="side" opened="true" [fixedInViewport]="true">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button class="menu-button">
                    <mat-icon svgIcon="server"></mat-icon>
                    <span> Servers</span>
                </button>        
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button class="menu-button">
                    <mat-icon svgIcon="site"></mat-icon>
                    <span> Sites</span>
                </button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button class="menu-button">
                    <mat-icon svgIcon="account"></mat-icon>
                    <span> Accounts</span>
                </button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button class="menu-button">
                    <mat-icon svgIcon="admin"></mat-icon>
                    <span> Admin</span>
                </button>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-nav-list>  
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and here is the typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatSidenav) sidenav: MatSidenav;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

when compiling that component the result I get is a toolbar hidden by the sidenav as shown in the figure below. Would you know what is wrong with my component ?

[image]

Comment: Thats the default behaviour. Ideally sidebar should always on top of everything. If you dont want that you need to override it using css styles.

Comment: I can see you have `mode="side"`, which does indicate that your sidenav should be shown alongside the main content. This leads me to think that perhaps you have CSS that is overriding Material's styles. Can you create a Stackblitz or similar?

Comment: unfortunately I do not know how to deposit a project on stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove below attribute from your sidebar component and you problem should be resolved.

```
[fixedInViewport]="true"
```

Stackblitz Example:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5n2bb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-overview-example.html

Comment: Doing so, the sidebar does not appear

Comment: Please check the link which I have provided. It working fine in that.

Comment: Yeap, your stackblitz works perfectly. I have to figure out why on my machine the sidebar disappears.

Comment: Copy your exact code in that stackblitz sample and then try. Let me know if you still facing issue. Happy to help.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I downloaded your code from stackblitz and ran it locally The sidebar still does not appear. So something is wrong on my machine but I do not know what.

Comment: Kindly share your OS details , ideally it should work.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04, angular/material 13.2.0